# How to choose multiplication monoid instead of addition monoid?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to merge two lists:

```
import scalaz.syntax.align._
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

List(1, 2, 3).merge(List(4, 5, 6, 7)) // Evaluates to List(5, 7, 9, 7)
```

This uses the standard addition monoid implicitly. What if I want use the multiplication monoid instead? What it is the idiomatic way to do this in Scalaz?

Comment: I guess you can do this with a Tag: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monoid.html#Tags.Multiplication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Multiplication` tag to indicate that you want to use the multiplication monoid:

```
import scalaz.Tags.Multiplication

val xs = List(1, 2, 3).map(Multiplication(_))
val ys = List(4, 5, 6, 7).map(Multiplication(_))
```

And then:

```
scala> xs merge ys
res0: List[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.Multiplication]] = List(4, 10, 18, 7)
```

`Multiplication.unwrap` removes the tag.

You could also explicitly pass in your own instance:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).merge(List(4, 5, 6, 7))(Monoid.instance(_ * _, 1))
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 10, 18, 7)
```

Using tags is more idiomatic, though.